# Replace / override default html tag with a React component

Tags: reactjs

I have a 3rd party library with a React component which looks something like this:

```js
const LibComponent = (props) => {
    // here be much logic and things...

    return (
        <div>
           // stuff
            <input name="in_a" blah="blah"... />
            // more stuff
           <input name="in_b" ... />
           // ...
        </div>
    )
}
```

(There is actually many such components in the library...)

I need to "replace" these `<input>` elements with my custom `<MyInput>` components.

Ideally I would "wrap" this 3rd party component and somehow alter its JSX before render. Then I could just use this wrapped component instead of `LibComponent`. Can this be done (without copy-pasting the `LibComponent`'s source code, of course)?

Comment: Have you thought of wrapping `input` inside `MyInput` with [styled-components](https://styled-components.com/docs/basics#styling-any-component)?